# Struggling to return GetFeatureInfo over QGIS Server and MapServer WMS layers

Tags: leaflet, wms, mapserver, getfeatureinfo, qgis-server

I have a HTML/Leaflet page utilising BetterWMS script (https://gist.github.com/rclark/6908938). The script returns GetFeatureInfo over WMS layers. Unfortunately it is not working with WMSs published by Qgis Server and MapServer, although ArcGIS Server and GeoServer services work fine. Below, you can find my full html file including BetterWMS script and relevant WMSs (all queryable).

Any tips about how to enhance the BetterWMS script so as to use with WMS layers published by servers in question?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    
    <title>Layers Control Tutorial - Leaflet</title>

    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="docs/images/favicon.ico" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-xodZBNTC5n17Xt2atTPuE1HxjVMSvLVW9ocqUKLsCC5CXdbqCmblAshOMAS6/keqq/sMZMZ19scR4PsZChSR7A==" crossorigin=""/>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha512-XQoYMqMTK8LvdxXYG3nZ448hOEQiglfqkJs1NOQV44cWnUrBc8PkAOcXy20w0vlaXaVUearIOBhiXZ5V3ynxwA==" crossorigin=""></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <style>
        html, body {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
        }
        #map {
            width: 1200px;
            height: 800px;
        }
    </style>
    
</head>
<body>

<div id='map'></div>

<script>

    // BetterWMS (https://gist.github.com/rclark/6908938)
    L.TileLayer.BetterWMS = L.TileLayer.WMS.extend({
      
      onAdd: function (map) {
        // Triggered when the layer is added to a map.
        //   Register a click listener, then do all the upstream WMS things
        L.TileLayer.WMS.prototype.onAdd.call(this, map);
        map.on('click', this.getFeatureInfo, this);
      },
      
      onRemove: function (map) {
        // Triggered when the layer is removed from a map.
        //   Unregister a click listener, then do all the upstream WMS things
        L.TileLayer.WMS.prototype.onRemove.call(this, map);
        map.off('click', this.getFeatureInfo, this);
      },
      
      getFeatureInfo: function (evt) {
        // Make an AJAX request to the server and hope for the best
        var url = this.getFeatureInfoUrl(evt.latlng),
          showResults = L.Util.bind(this.showGetFeatureInfo, this);
        $.ajax({
          url: url,
          success: function (data, status, xhr) {
            var err = typeof data === 'string' ? null : data;
            //Fix for blank popup window
            var doc = (new DOMParser()).parseFromString(data, "text/html"); 
            if (doc.body.innerHTML.trim().length > 0)
              showResults(err, evt.latlng, data);
          },
          error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            showResults(error);
          }
        });
      },
      
      getFeatureInfoUrl: function (latlng) {
        // Construct a GetFeatureInfo request URL given a point
        var point = this._map.latLngToContainerPoint(latlng, this._map.getZoom()),
            size = this._map.getSize(),
            
            params = {
              request: 'GetFeatureInfo',
              service: 'WMS',
              srs: 'EPSG:4326',
              styles: this.wmsParams.styles,
              transparent: this.wmsParams.transparent,
              version: this.wmsParams.version,      
              format: this.wmsParams.format,
              bbox: this._map.getBounds().toBBoxString(),
              height: size.y,
              width: size.x,
              layers: this.wmsParams.layers,
              query_layers: this.wmsParams.layers,
              info_format: 'text/html'
            };
        
        params[params.version === '1.3.0' ? 'i' : 'x'] = point.x;
        params[params.version === '1.3.0' ? 'j' : 'y'] = point.y;
        
        return this._url + L.Util.getParamString(params, this._url, true);
      },
      
      showGetFeatureInfo: function (err, latlng, content) {
        if (err) { console.log(err); return; } // do nothing if there's an error

        // Otherwise show the content in a popup, or something.
        L.popup({ maxWidth: 800, minWidth: 0, autoPan: false })
          .setLatLng(latlng)
          .setContent(content)
          .openOn(this._map);
      }
    });

    L.tileLayer.betterWms = function (url, options) {
      return new L.TileLayer.BetterWMS(url, options);  
    };
    // BetterWMS
        
    var mbAttr = 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, ' +
            'Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
        mbUrl = 'https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{id}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4NXVycTA2emYycXBndHRqcmZ3N3gifQ.rJcFIG214AriISLbB6B5aw';

    var grayscale   = L.tileLayer(mbUrl, {id: 'mapbox/light-v9', tileSize: 512, zoomOffset: -1, attribution: mbAttr}),
        streets  = L.tileLayer(mbUrl, {id: 'mapbox/streets-v11', tileSize: 512, zoomOffset: -1, attribution: mbAttr});
        
    var arcgis = L.tileLayer.betterWms('https://nowcoast.noaa.gov/arcgis/services/nowcoast/forecast_meteoceanhydro_pts_zones_geolinks/MapServer/WMSServer',{
        maxZoom: 21, format: 'image/png', layers: '1', transparent: true});

    var geoserver = L.tileLayer.betterWms('https://www.mrlc.gov/geoserver/mrlc_display/NLCD_2016_Land_Cover_L48/wms',{
        maxZoom: 21, format: 'image/png', layers: 'NLCD_2016_Land_Cover_L48', transparent: true});      
        
    var qgis = L.tileLayer.betterWms('https://ows.geo.hu-berlin.de/cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi',{
        maxZoom: 21, format: 'image/png', layers: 'sen2', transparent: true});  

    var mapserver = L.tileLayer.betterWms('https://demo.mapserver.org/cgi-bin/wms',{
        maxZoom: 21, format: 'image/png', layers: 'cities', transparent: true});    

    var map = L.map('map', {
        center: [40, -98],
        zoom: 5,
        layers: [grayscale]
    });

    var baseLayers = {
        "Grayscale": grayscale,
        "Streets": streets,
    };

    var overlays = {
        "Arcgis Server": arcgis,
        "GeoServer": geoserver,
        "Qgis Server": qgis,
        "MapServer": mapserver,
    };

    L.control.layers(baseLayers, overlays, { collapsed: false }).addTo(map);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please, don't ask the same question again: [BetterWMS script doesn't work with QGIS Server and MapServer WMSs](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/401933/betterwms-script-doesnt-work-with-qgis-server-and-mapserver-wmss)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has nothing to do with QGIS Server or MapServer but how these two sample servers are set up:

For both the CORS-Header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' is missing:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin

The browser console shows the following message:

[image]

I'm afraid the only thing you can do is to ask the server administrators if they are willing to set this header.

Comment: Alternative solution would be to use local proxy server to fetch GetFeatureInfo.

Comment: Thank you very much @pathmapper. I had a chance to test it on another Qgis Server. As you mentioned, after enabling CORS on Apache, feature info started to be obtained.